# performance anomaly in identity matrix creation

Tags: c, matrix, performance-testing, memset

Firstly, sorry for my terrible English.

I wrote an program for finding best way to create an identity matrix dynamically in a function. I have three function for creating an identity matrix. First function and second function almost same. Only difference between them is: First function use `memset` function for filling the array with zeros, second function does this built-in. The last function makes everything only in one loop with using conditional statements. I was thinking using conditional statements will slow down the function unnecessarily.

Performance comparison result of the code was interesting, reverse of all of my guesses:

```
1: 1194 
2: 551 
3: 440
```

How last function, which using conditional statement, can be faster than all other? `memset` is a long time developed function, how it is can be slower than my built-in code?

Source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <time.h>

typedef float MAT4[4][4];

void identityMatrix_1(MAT4 matrix)
{
    memset(matrix, 0, sizeof(matrix[0][0]) * 4 * 4);

    for(int I = 0; I < 4; I++)
    {
        matrix[I][I] = 1;
    }
}

void identityMatrix_2(MAT4 matrix)
{
    for(int X = 0; X < 4; X++)
    {
        for(int Y = 0; Y < 4; Y++)
        {   
            matrix[X][Y] = 0;
        }
    }

    for(int I = 0; I < 4; I++)
    {
        matrix[I][I] = 1;
    }
}

void identityMatrix_3(MAT4 matrix)
{
    for(int X = 0; X < 4; X++)
    {
        for(int Y = 0; Y < 4; Y++)
        {   
            if(X == Y)
            {
                matrix[X][Y] = 1;
            }
            else
            {       
                matrix[X][Y] = 0;
            }       
        }
    }

}

void printMAT4(MAT4 matrix)
{
    for(int X = 0; X < 4; X++)
    {
        for(int Y = 0; Y < 4; Y++)
        {   
            printf("%f ",matrix[X][Y]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

clock_t startTime, endTime;

int main(void) {
    MAT4 i1, i2, i3;

    startTime = clock();
    for(int I = 0; I < 10000; I++)
        identityMatrix_1(i1);
    endTime = clock();

    printf("1: %li \n", endTime - startTime);

    startTime = clock();
    for(int I = 0; I < 10000; I++)
        identityMatrix_2(i2);
    endTime = clock();

    printf("2: %li \n", endTime - startTime);

    startTime = clock();
    for(int I = 0; I < 10000; I++)
        identityMatrix_3(i3);
    endTime = clock();

    printf("3: %li \n", endTime - startTime);


//for optimizing the code correctly.
printMAT4(i1);
printMAT4(i2);
printMAT4(i3);

    return 0;
}
```

Edit: **I do not optimize the program.**

Edit: **I edited the program according to answers and optimize the program.**

**Optimized results (-O3):**

```
1: 188 
2: 0 
3: 0
```

Comment: What compiler are you using and what flags if any?

Comment: If you don't turn on optimization for the code, it is like watching Usain Bolt walking. Not very fast, and extremely uninteresting.

Comment: I'm using GCC. I optimize it.

Answer (score 1):

If you compile this with optimizations turned on, the compiler will likely notice that you never read from your matrix and as such it is valid to just remove your identityMatrix functions.

If you're not compiling with optimizations turned off the compiler won't optimize your functions away so you'll get timings, but they are meaningless because they differ a lot from what you'll get with optimizations turned on.

Comment: i edit the program according to your answer. And optimize it.